# Arch/ XFCE - Disable global keyboard grabbing for gcr/ gnome-keyring

Tags: gnome-keyring, pinentry

I am using gnome-keyring as ssh-agent on my arch/ xfce system.
Since I have multiple ssh-keys, I additionally have a password manager to store their keys.

Adding those ssh-keys to the keyring works without any problems, however, I noticed that the password prompt grabs the keyboard entirely even if the window is not focused. That behavior prevents proper usage of the password manager, so I would like to disable it.

Apparently gnome-keyring uses gcr to create its password prompts.
Is there any way you can change the behavior of gcr globally to only grab the keyboard on focus or alternatively, is there a way to use alternative prompt generators, e.g. pinentry that have options to disable global keyboard grabbing?